# Woocommerce separate title and variation from mini cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
<a class="minicart-product-title" href="url-to-product">
  <div class="minicart-image"><img width="128" height="100" src="url-to-image" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy"></div>my product - green</a>
```

This is `html` output of mini cart product item, I need to separate title and variation something like this:

```
<a class="minicart-product-title" href="url-to-product">
  <div class="minicart-image"><img width="128" height="100" src="url-to-image" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy"></div<h3>>my product</h3> - <span>green</span></a>
```

But I edit `mini-cart.php` and find this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>">
                            <?php echo $thumbnail . wp_kses_post( $product_name ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                        </a>
```

And there is `wp_kses_post` to generate this title, but I don't know how to add some `html` to it?

Comment: `wp_kses_post` doesn't generate the title, but sanitizes the output of product name. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply clone and override `mini-cart.php` in your theme then, find this line:

```
if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
```

**Append:**

```
$product_title = $_product->get_title( $cart_item );
```

Now `echo $product_title`, note that `get_name()` return product name with variation name, but `get_title()` return title only.